# ggplot2 yaxis limit changes the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's my data

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mveo3csln8mafx8/test.csv?dl=0

I am using ggplot to plot `fit` as a percentage of `mean.nc` against `x`

```
ggplot() + 
geom_line(data=test,aes(y = (fit-mean.nc)/mean.nc*100, x=x)) +
geom_ribbon(data=test,aes(x= x, ymin= (se.lw - mean.nc)/mean.nc *100,
                        ymax= (se.up - mean.nc)/mean.nc*100),alpha=0.2)
```

[image]

I wanto to increase the range of y-axis so I added an extra argument using `ylim`

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=test,aes(y = (fit-mean.nc)/mean.nc*100, x=x)) +
  geom_ribbon(data=test,aes(x= x, ymin= (se.lw - mean.nc)/mean.nc *100,
                    ymax= (se.up - mean.nc)/mean.nc*100),alpha=0.2) +
  ylim(-70,70)
```

[image]

As you can see, my line extends beyond the actual data. I am not sure why is this happening given that `ylim` should
only change my y-axis and do nothing to my actually graph. Can anyone advise me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: ? You decreased your range it seems to me.. Why is it beyond your actual data? The ribbon is being cut off because of your limited y range.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to increase my range and it works now. I guess this question is not useful for the community so I will delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ylim` and `xlim` do indeed subset the data.
What you are looking for is probably inside `coord_cartesian`

```
ggplot() + 
geom_line(data=test, aes(y = (fit-mean.nc)/mean.nc*100, x = x)) +
geom_ribbon(data=test, aes(x = x, ymin= (se.lw - mean.nc) / mean.nc * 100,
                        ymax = (se.up - mean.nc) / mean.nc * 100), alpha = 0.2) +
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-70, 70))
```